# Update all records to remove first 3 letters of string SQL MS Access 2013?

Tags: sql, ms-access

There is a set of data that I pulled from a server and in one of the fields, every value has the first 3 letters "DFT" with 2 or 3 letters following that. I want to use an SQL statement along the lines of:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=[string after first 3 letters]
WHERE [first 3 letters of string]='DFT';
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you haven't specified which db you're using, but they ALL have string functions, e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, updated the title now. I'm using Access 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1 = MID(column1, 4, LEN(column1) - 3)
WHERE MID(column1, 1, 3) = 'DFT'
```